# Read requests and responses made by browser on naviagating a web page in C# webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I wants to read all the requests and responses made and get by the browser on navigating on a page.

For ex:
If I navigate to http://www.yahoo.com then
we observe that browser is making a lots of GET and post requests.
For the purpose of image loading, content loading and to display the Ads (Advertisement).

I am using selenium web driver and C#.

Can you please help me how can I get all the requests (get/post) and responses.

Thanks,
Ramesh Jhajharia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to accomplish this is to use some sort of scriptable proxy. One such proxy is the [BrowserMob proxy](https://github.com/webmetrics/browsermob-proxy), and there's even a [.NET wrapper](https://github.com/AutomatedTester/AutomatedTester.BrowserMob) for it. This would allow you to gather information that is outside the scope of WebDriver, such as the raw HTTP requests that you are asking for.

Comment: HI thanks Jim.....I got my answers ......and I found a link also (http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2012/02/automating-web-performance-stats.html) which can help new users.