# Capturing URL while Selenium Tests run

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, wireshark, fiddlercore

i am automating using selenium webdriver and C#. Is there a way to capture all urls that my browser navigates to while my Selenium automation tests run using an external tool such as Fiddler core / wireshark. I mean while my tests continue to run, I would like some of these tools to capture my urls  parallely so that incase my tests fail, i could investigate further by using the final few urls(from the point of failure) to debug the issue.

Is this really possible. Do I need to use a separate thread to one of these tools(Fiddler/wireshark/any other tool) to capture the url?

Can this really be done

Comment: How about this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11053449/2504101 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options.

1. Start wireshark (or fiddler) before your Selenium test kicks off.  You can do this with a batch file that gets executed in your test setup.
2. <del>You can utilize a browser plugin for fiddler.  IE has one, I'm not sure if there is a comparible plugin for all browsers though.  Then you can get Selenium to activate this through the browser...assuming fiddler keeps in the browser window and not open a separate non-browser window that Selenium can't see.</del>**UPDATE**: Fiddler plugins don't stay in the browser window so this option won't work.
3. Write some wrapper code that does a `driver.Url` and stores it into a list.  This wrapper code would check to see if the `driver.Url` is different from the last stored entry in the object and if it is different then it would add it to the list.

All have pros and cons.  3 would give you the most control as your test itself would gather the URL's and maintain a list in code that you can do what you want with.  1 of course would give you the most robust details, depending on how you setup wireshark, and you can profile the entire machine and network experience.  2 is a middle ground where your test still drives it, but the results are separate...but being part of the browser you would have to avoid cleanup after your tests...if you have more tests than one execute at a time this could cause alot of problems...

Comment: Thanks, the driver.url worked. i made the url capturing to run in a separate thread and called it recursively. Im saving to a text file once the test case fails. 
Very simple solution, but it works great!

Comment: Fiddler's IE plugin simply launches the tool, it doesn't do anything else at all. The Firefox plugin optionally points Firefox's settings at Fiddler, but that's it.

Comment: Totally correct...which makes option 2 above wrong...I'll scratch that out

Comment: Do any of you guys know whether it's possible to integrate Selenium + Fiddler Core with cloud testing, such as https://www.browserstack.com/?